# Confusion about Python Functions and Lists

Tags: python

I am trying to create a function to remove an item from the passed list either by a specified index, or item passed.

If the user wishes to remove an item from the list using an index, the third argument passed will be `“index”`, if the user wishes to remove the first item found in the list using the item passed, the second argument will be `“{item}”`

For example, to remove the item at index 3 from a list, this would be the command `myFunction(myList,3,”index”)`

I am quite confused about this function part.  I have written code that does exactly what the question seems to ask, but it does not use a function.  My code is below :

```
mylist = ["one" , "two" ,"three" , "four" , "five"]
print "list is composed of: "+ str(mylist)
name = raw_input("Index of item to be removed. ex.  1")
name2 = raw_input('"item to be removed. ex. four')
name3 = int(name)
del mylist[name3]
mylist.remove(name2)
print mylist
```

It appears that I need to create a function to do this, and then pass in my list, the index/item, etc.)  but I am very lost on this part.

Comment: Your code does **both**, delete by index and by value.

Comment: Doesn't EDX teach how to define functions with `def myFunction()`?

Comment: Yes I know my code does both,  but it is asking to do this code as part of a function which is where I am confused using the myfunction(mylist,3,"index") etc...  @barmar if you have a link to that page I would love it,  the pdf i am going from does not specfically define how to do that.  And I am sorry if these are really simple questions, I am quite new to this

Comment: I don't know anything about EDX. But how could they give a homework assignment that depends on something they haven't taught yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question (I think) is:   "*If the user wishes to remove an item from the list using an index, the third argument passed will be “index”, if the user wishes to remove the first item found in the list using the item passed, the second argument will be “{item}”*"

The purpose of this exercise (presumably) is to practice writing a function.  Yes you could do it without a function but right now you need the practice of writing a function and passing parameters.  Functions are a very important part of programming, but this is not a good place to go into that.

So first we define our function:

```
def removeItem( theList, theItem, typeOfItem=None ):
```

Notice I have given a default value of `None` because the third parameter is optional.

The first thing we will do is to test `typeOfItem`.  The question says that is it is an index then it will say `"index"` else the second parameter will say `"{item}"`.  So it will be one or the other.  (What to do if that is not the case is a question you should ask).

The index part is easy:

```
    if typeOfItem == "index":
        del(theList[theItem])
```

but now its a bit more complicated, because of the `{  }`, which we have to remove:

```
    else:
        theList.remove(theItem[1:-1])
```

This last part is removing a *slice*, which starts at character 1 (the second character) and ends at the final character -1, thus removing the `{ }`

So the final function code, with tests, is:

```
def removeItem( theList, theItem, typeOfItem=None ):
    if typeOfItem == "index":
        del(theList[theItem])
    else:
        theList.remove(theItem[1:-1])

mylist = ["one" , "two" ,"three" , "four" , "five"]
removeItem(mylist, 3, "index")
print mylist

mylist = ["one" , "two" ,"three" , "four" , "five"]
removeItem(mylist, "{two}")
print mylist
```

Notice an important feature of the function and the list.  If you alter the list inside the function then it also alters it *outside* the function as well - it is the same list.  That is not the case with numbers and strings.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to work on your questionsmithing skills. It's very difficult to understand what you are trying to accomplish. After making about half a dozen assumptions, I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
def listRemover(mylist,index_or_name,mytype):
    if mytype == "index":
        del mylist[index_or_name]

    if mytype == "name":
        mylist.remove(index_or_name)
```

It's obvious though that there are some gaping holes in your basic knowledge of python. You need to study what a function is, why they are useful, and how to use them.

Comment: I have only been doing this for 2 weeks now, so yes there are many holes in my knowledge :/

Comment: Using a variable called `type` is not a good idea, it will mask the builtin of the same name.

Comment: @ed.hank See but when you use stack overflow as a crutch to fill in basic holes in your knowledge, you overwhelm the people that have intermediate to advanced knowledge. If you find yourself "very lost" on basic concepts, then Stack Overflow should not be your go-to. Your professor or your TA should be your first line of defense.

Comment: Ah, check, i will delete my question then.  sorry about that :/  Well I tried to delete it and it said a moderator needs to.  If one of yall could delete it that would be fine.  sorry again :/

Comment: No problem. Lots of newbies do it, you are definitely not the first. Also, try answering a few python questions once you get a little better. Lots of people stop by to help themselves, but very few stick around to help others.

Answer (score 1):

> It appears that I need to create a function to do this, and then pass in my list, the index/item, etc.) but I am very lost on this part.

[Google it!](https://www.google.com/webhp#q=define+function+python) (query = "define function python")

Show your research. The basic form of a function is:

```
def funcname(arg1, arg2, arg3):
   # now you can use the vars arg1, arg2, and arg3.
   # rename them to whatever you want.
   arg1[0] = "bannanas"
```

so,

```
array = ['mango', 'apple']
funcname(array)
print(array) # -> ['bannanas', 'apple']
```